# varnish: How to keep user cookies while caching per page not per user

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a page that have a content that will be displayed to all users, but the issue is I have an ajax call done after page load this call is not cacheable but it requires cookies which is removed from the cached page, what can I do to to keep the cookies and still get the cached page?

Comment: Postin it for the second time :P Are you aware of this https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies

Comment: I read that and I'm fully aware that it can be done by adding cookies to hash but it will result to have a per user cache, this is not what I want to accomplish cause there is no gain via this method - actually there is a little gain but not noticable.

Comment: Please, paste your `vcl` contents

Answer (score 1):

In vcl_hash routine you can decide exactly how to hash your requests. For instance the following would only hash on the request URI and not include cookies:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    set req.hash += req.url;
    set req.hash += req.http.host;
}
```

Do note that you probably want to exclude the ajax call and any other requests that are not cacheable in your configuration. Or even better, let the backend send a header if the request is cacheable and let varnish act on that.

Just beware of caching pages with setcookie and it should be alright.